# How to do in-place processing of a specific set of numpy array rows

Tags: python, numpy

In the following example, I would like to modify a specific set of rows as a group, `in-place`. The first call to *inplace_process* seems to result in a copy of the array being passed whereas the second call to *inplace_process* modifies the *x* variable directly.

The size of the array in my actual use case is too large to create a copy and I'm calling code that is external to my project.

```
import numpy as np

def inplace_process(a, C, N):
    a.shape = (C, N)
    a[:, :] = float(C*N)

C = 4
N = 128
x = np.zeros((C, N))

# process a specific set of rows
inplace_process(x[(0, 1, 3), :], 3, N)
# independently process an inner row
inplace_process(x[2, :], 1, N)

print '-----------------------------------------------------'
print ' We want C*N and not zeros'
print x
```

*Outputs*:

```
[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [ 128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.
   128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.  128.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
     0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i believe op is asking why the first example copies where as the other does it by reference.  Maybe since you're selecting non-continuous set of rows, it returns a copy?  Selecting by a non-mutable index returns a copy?

Comment: The question is how can I pass a reference to a specific set of numpy rows to a function for in-place processing or modification?

Answer (score 1):

In NumPy, ["basic slices"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), such as `x[2, :]`, return views.

So-called ["advanced
indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing),
such as `x[(0,1,3), :]`, returns copies of the array.

Under the hood, NumPy arrays store values in a contiguous block of memory and
access the values based on `dtype`, `shape` and `strides`. The values
themselves may be non-contiguous within that block of memory depending on the strides, but nevertheless each array references values from a single block of memory.

Advanced indexing allows you to select *arbitrary* rows from this block of memory.
In general there is no way to specify the resultant array using the original
block of memory, and just a dtype, shape and strides.  Therefore the resultant array's values must be
copied into a new array.  This is why advanced indexing always returns a copy.

Modification of a copy of an array (as one would expect) does not affect the original array. This is why passing  `x[(0, 1, 3), :]` to `inplace_place` does not affect `x`.

However, assignments -- even if the left-hand side uses advanced indexing -- do affect the original array. For example

```
x[(0, 1, 3), :] = C*N
```

would affect `x`. Therefore, you can fix the code by passing the rows to `inplace_process` and performing the assignment to `a[rows, :]` there:

```
import numpy as np

def inplace_process(a, rows, C, N):
    a[rows, :] = float(C*N)

C = 4
N = 128
x = np.zeros((C, N))

# process a specific set of rows
inplace_process(x, (0, 1, 3), 3, N)
# independently process an inner row
inplace_process(x, [2], 1, N)
```